# Swift: Error loading /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/NRDAudioClient: no suitable image found

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, ios-simulator

I am trying to play a sound as follows:

```
import AVFoundation

let sound = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "audiofile", ofType: "wav")!)
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    @IBAction func audio1(_ sender: Any) {

        do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: sound)
            audioPlayer.play()
        } catch {
            // error
        }
```

When running in the iOS simulator this results in the following:

> 2019-01-08 12:29:55.438490+0800 Test App[8096:118590] Error loading
>   /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/NRDAudioClient.plugin/Contents/MacOS/NRDAudioClient:
>   dlopen(/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/NRDAudioClient.plugin/Contents/MacOS/NRDAudioClient,
>   262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
>
> /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/NRDAudioClient.plugin/Contents/MacOS/NRDAudioClient:
>   mach-o, but not built for iOS simulator
>
> 2019-01-08 12:29:55.438703+0800 Test App[8096:118590] Cannot find
>   function pointer NRDACLN_New_Instance for factory  3E9FAD07-70A8-4980-B39B-BB8B905C9872 in
>   CFBundle/CFPlugIn 0x7fcf5b135210
>    (bundle, not
>   loaded)

I haven't found any information at all on what "NRDAudioClient" is. I am using macincloud so am not sure if this error is related to a specific setup there.

Answer (score 1):

Click on Product -> Clean (or CMD-Shift-K)

Or by manually cleaning the Xcode setting files:

rm -rf "$(getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR)/org.llvm.clang/ModuleCache"
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode

I have no idea why though. Good luck see if it helps.

Hope this works for you.