# Playing audio using Xamarin forms fails with error: NRDAudioClient not built for iOS simulator

Tags: ios, xamarin, audio

I am trying to play an audio sound with my Xamarin Forms application. In the iOS implementation I call this code (url is full path of the file I want to play):

```
    this.player = new AVPlayer();
    this.player = AVPlayer.FromUrl(NSUrl.FromString(url));
    this.player.Play();
```

I see the following error when I run it in a simulator:

```
2019-06-18 19:02:18.310742+0100 Animalike2App.iOS[11991:167215] SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error=22 cs_flags=200, pid=11991
2019-06-18 19:02:18.311079+0100 Animalike2App.iOS[11991:167215] SecTaskCopyDebugDescription: Animalike2App.iO[11991]/0#-1 LF=0
2019-06-18 19:02:18.490415+0100 Animalike2App.iOS[11991:167215] SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error=22 cs_flags=200, pid=11991
2019-06-18 19:02:18.490964+0100 Animalike2App.iOS[11991:167215] SecTaskCopyDebugDescription: Animalike2App.iO[11991]/0#-1 LF=0
2019-06-18 19:02:18.670057+0100 Animalike2App.iOS[11991:167176] Error loading /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/NRDAudioClient.plugin/Contents/MacOS/NRDAudioClient:  dlopen(/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/NRDAudioClient.plugin/Contents/MacOS/NRDAudioClient, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/NRDAudioClient.plugin/Contents/MacOS/NRDAudioClient: mach-o, but not built for iOS simulator
2019-06-18 19:02:18.670271+0100 Animalike2App.iOS[11991:167176] Cannot find function pointer NRDACLN_New_Instance for factory <CFUUID 0x6040016385a0> 3E9FAD07-70A8-4980-B39B-BB8B905C9872 in CFBundle/CFPlugIn 0x7ff70a45d0f0 </Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/NRDAudioClient.plugin> (bundle, not loaded)
2019-06-18 19:02:21.185424+0100 Animalike2App.iOS[11991:167198] [aqme] 177: timed out after 0.012s (128 128); suspension count=0 (IOSuspensions: )
```

I work on a windows PC, and to run the code connect to Mac machine using macincloud.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try the [answer posted here?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54086993/8395242). It wasn't accepted, and I don't know if MacInCloud gives you the terminal access required, but it may be worth a shot.

Comment: @alexander zark Which is the version of Visual tudio and iOS Deployment Target .You can show the url , I will check it.